# Embedding an R htmlwidget into existing webpage

Tags: r, htmlwidgets

I am trying to embed an `R` [`htmlwidget`](http://www.htmlwidgets.org/) into an existing webpage -- a webpage that already has bootstrap and styling applied. For example, consider the following webpage (note where the widget should be placed):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>This is a test.</p>
  <!-- htmlwidget should go here. -->
  <p>A closing paragraph.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I can create and save a [`datatable`](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/) widget like so:

```r
library(htmlwidgets)
library(datatable)

d1 <- datatable(mtcars, filter = "top")
saveWidget(d1, file = "widget_file.html")
```

The generated `widget_file.html` (even for this modest widget) contains a lot of code. Is there an easy way to embed this into an existing webpage/template?

I have been successful using `<iframe src="widget_file.html">` but I'm wondering if there is a better way? Moreover, is there a way to separate pieces/dependencies (e.g. `json` data) from the `widget_file.html` so they can be placed in other folders?

---

*Note: I created the `htmlwidget` tag, but I believe there should be a synonymous `htmlwidgets` tag.*

Comment: That may be possible. See: http://brendanrocks.com/htmlwidgets-knitr-jekyll/.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `htmlwidget`-Package offers a way to save the pieces for the widget separately as follows:

```
library(dygraphs)
d1 <- dygraph(nhtemp, main = "New Haven Temperatures") %>% 
  dyRangeSelector(dateWindow = c("1920-01-01", "1960-01-01"))

saveWidget(d1, file = "widget_file.html", selfcontained = FALSE)
```

Which results in the following files/dirs:

```
widget_file.html
widget_file_files
  /dygraphs-1.1.1
    ..
  /dygraphs-binding-0.6
    ..
  /htmlwidgets-0.5
    ..
  /jquery-1.11.1
    ..
  /moment-2.8.4  
    ..
  /moment-timezone-0.2.5
    ..
```

And `widget_file.html` reads as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<script src="widget_file_files/htmlwidgets-0.5/htmlwidgets.js"></script>
...
<script src="widget_file_files/dygraphs-binding-0.6/dygraphs.js"></script>

</head>
<body style="background-color:white;">
<div id="htmlwidget_container">
  <div id="htmlwidget-2956" style="width:960px;height:500px;" class="dygraphs"></div>
</div>

<!-- THE JSON DATA -->
<script type="application/json" data-for="htmlwidget-2956">
{THE JSON DATA YOU WERE LOOKING FOR}
</script>
<!-- THE JSON DATA -->

<script type="application/htmlwidget-sizing" data-for="htmlwidget-2956">{Widget-Styling-Json}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

So you can edit your html as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <!-- Begin of scripts to run the widget -->
  <script src="widget_file_files/htmlwidgets-0.5/htmlwidgets.js"></script>
  <script src="widget_file_files/jquery-1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="widget_file_files/dygraphs-1.1.1/dygraph.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="widget_file_files/dygraphs-1.1.1/dygraph-combined.js"></script>
  <script src="widget_file_files/moment-2.8.4/moment.js"></script>
  <script src="widget_file_files/moment-timezone-0.2.5/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>
  <script src="widget_file_files/dygraphs-binding-0.6/dygraphs.js"></script>
  <!-- End of scripts to run the widget -->

  <!-- Begin Widget styling -->
    <script type="application/htmlwidget-sizing" data-for="htmlwidget-2956">{"viewer":{"width":450,"height":350,"padding":10,"fill":true},"browser":{"width":960,"height":500,"padding":40,"fill":true}}</script>
  <!-- End widget Styling -->

  <!-- Begin Data for the widget-->
  <script type="application/json" data-for="htmlwidget-2956">{"x":{"attrs":{"title":"New Haven Temperatures","labels":["year","V1"],"legend":"auto","retainDateWindow":false,"axes":{"x":{"pixelsPerLabel":60}},"showRangeSelector":true,"dateWindow":["1920-01-01T00:00:00Z","1960-01-01T00:00:00Z"],"rangeSelectorHeight":40,"rangeSelectorPlotFillColor":" #A7B1C4","rangeSelectorPlotStrokeColor":"#808FAB","interactionModel":"Dygraph.Interaction.defaultModel"},"scale":"yearly","annotations":[],"shadings":[],"events":[],"format":"date","data":[["1912-01-01T00:00:00Z","1913-01-01T00:00:00Z","1914-01-01T00:00:00Z","1915-01-01T00:00:00Z","1916-01-01T00:00:00Z","1917-01-01T00:00:00Z","1918-01-01T00:00:00Z","1919-01-01T00:00:00Z","1920-01-01T00:00:00Z","1921-01-01T00:00:00Z","1922-01-01T00:00:00Z","1923-01-01T00:00:00Z","1924-01-01T00:00:00Z","1925-01-01T00:00:00Z","1926-01-01T00:00:00Z","1927-01-01T00:00:00Z","1928-01-01T00:00:00Z","1929-01-01T00:00:00Z","1930-01-01T00:00:00Z","1931-01-01T00:00:00Z","1932-01-01T00:00:00Z","1933-01-01T00:00:00Z","1934-01-01T00:00:00Z","1935-01-01T00:00:00Z","1936-01-01T00:00:00Z","1937-01-01T00:00:00Z","1938-01-01T00:00:00Z","1939-01-01T00:00:00Z","1940-01-01T00:00:00Z","1941-01-01T00:00:00Z","1942-01-01T00:00:00Z","1943-01-01T00:00:00Z","1944-01-01T00:00:00Z","1945-01-01T00:00:00Z","1946-01-01T00:00:00Z","1947-01-01T00:00:00Z","1948-01-01T00:00:00Z","1949-01-01T00:00:00Z","1950-01-01T00:00:00Z","1951-01-01T00:00:00Z","1952-01-01T00:00:00Z","1953-01-01T00:00:00Z","1954-01-01T00:00:00Z","1955-01-01T00:00:00Z","1956-01-01T00:00:00Z","1957-01-01T00:00:00Z","1958-01-01T00:00:00Z","1959-01-01T00:00:00Z","1960-01-01T00:00:00Z","1961-01-01T00:00:00Z","1962-01-01T00:00:00Z","1963-01-01T00:00:00Z","1964-01-01T00:00:00Z","1965-01-01T00:00:00Z","1966-01-01T00:00:00Z","1967-01-01T00:00:00Z","1968-01-01T00:00:00Z","1969-01-01T00:00:00Z","1970-01-01T00:00:00Z","1971-01-01T00:00:00Z"],[49.9,52.3,49.4,51.1,49.4,47.9,49.8,50.9,49.3,51.9,50.8,49.6,49.3,50.6,48.4,50.7,50.9,50.6,51.5,52.8,51.8,51.1,49.8,50.2,50.4,51.6,51.8,50.9,48.8,51.7,51,50.6,51.7,51.5,52.1,51.3,51,54,51.4,52.7,53.1,54.6,52,52,50.9,52.6,50.2,52.6,51.6,51.9,50.5,50.9,51.7,51.4,51.7,50.8,51.9,51.8,51.9,53]]},"evals":["attrs.interactionModel"]}</script>
  <!-- End Data for the widget-->
</head>
<body>
  <p>This is a test.</p>
  <div id="htmlwidget_container">
    <div id="htmlwidget-2956" style="width:960px;height:500px;" class="dygraphs"></div>
  </div>
  <p>A closing paragraph.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

This will leave you with the json-data hardcoded within the html-document (see my  ).
If you want to load the data dynamically you can use e.g.

```
json_dat <- readLines("widget_file.html")[18]
cat(sub("</script>","",sub('<script type=\"application/json\" data-for=.*\">', "", json_dat)), file = "./widget_file_files/my_data.json")
```

To save the json-data as `./widget_file_files/my_data.json` and then load it within the html. If you are using PHP you can do:

```
<script type="application/json" data-for="htmlwidget-2956">
    <?php include('widget_file_files/my_data.json'); ?>
</script>
```

If you want to use a pure JS solution maybe have a look at http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/ and the `widget_file_files/htmlwidgets-0.5/htmlwidgets.js`-File how the json-data is bound at the moment...

P.S.:
As this question got a lot of attention already you could also contact the package developer and ask him to further "un-selfcontain" the "selfcontained" option in `htmlwidgets:::saveWidget`: Meaning to save the json-data separately and include it e.g. via `jquery.getjson`

Comment: can you please answer my question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68094669/how-to-change-the-font-size-color-and-style-while-setting-engine-htmlwidget) regarding htmlwidget? This will help me a lot.