# Add custom js file to R html widget output?

Tags: r, plotly, htmlwidgets

I am using R htmlwidget package, which save plotly graph in the form of html.The function `htmlwidget::savewidget()`save graph as a html file. Now we need to include a custom js file to the plotly html file generated by `htmlwidget::savewidget()` for additional operation, like clicking on the graph etc ...
e.g My custom.js file contains the following code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('#htmlwidget_container').on('plotly_click', function(data){
alert('You clicked this Plotly chart!');
 });
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add javascript through htmlwidget function  **onStaticRenderComplete()**

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////
                     javascript <- HTML(paste("

                       //here write your own javscript 

                         ", sep=''))

                      //pass this  javascript to prepend function and assign 
                         it to your graph object.

                    p <- prependContent(p,onStaticRenderComplete(javascript))

                   htmlwidgets::saveWidget(p, plotlyoutput, selfcontained = 
                   FALSE)
```

Another method for external js file is ::

follow this link

[Embedding an R htmlwidget into existing webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34439928/embedding-an-r-htmlwidget-into-existing-webpage?rq=1)